# Custom Date Picker Based On MatDatePicker - Open Picker and Focus Input

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular7

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-picker-component)

Hi community
I created a custom date picker component that is based on the Angular Material DatePicker. It has the following additional features:

- input mask for German date format
- Opening calendar when clicking input field

When clicking input field (background color: brown), the calendar opens and the input field is focused. So the user can either choose a date from the calendar or type it manually into the input field.

When clicking the mat-form-field (background color: white), the input field gets focused by default. I grap the click event to additionally open the datepicker:

```
<mat-form-field (click)="datePicker.open();">
```

The calendar opens but the input field does not get focused. Even when I add the focus-method to the click-eventhandler, the input field does not get focused:

```
 <mat-form-field (click)="datePicker.open(); input.focus()">
```

It seems like I had to choose if I'd like to have the calendar open or the input field focused when clicking the mat-form-field, but I want both :-)

Another unsuccessful approach was to grap the onContainerClick event of the mat-form-field.

I also tried to call the `input.click()` method in the `mat-form-field.click()` method but also without success.

Any ideas how I can achieve the same behaviour on clicking the mat-form-field that I get when clicking the input field?

Thank you very much.

Comment: but the stackblitz you attached is working fine

Comment: @hana_wujira Unfortunately it isn't. Please click the white area (mat-form-field) --> the calendar opens but the input is not focused, the cursor is not in the input field so that you could start to type a date

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded in just putting the `this.dateInput.nativeElement.focus()` method call into a setTimeout function:

Template:

```
<mat-form-field (click)="datePicker.open(); focusInputField();">
```

code behind:

```
  focusInputField() {
    setTimeout(() => this.dateInput.nativeElement.focus());
  }
```

I updated the stackblitz example.